# K-Theory and completion

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-k-theory

I vaguely remember the existence of a statement that relates the $K$-theory (in the sense of Quillen) of a noetherian local ring $A$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ with the $K$-theory of the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion $\hat{A}$ of $A$.

**Question 1:** Is there any hope that the two spectra $K(A)$ and $K(\hat{A})$ are homotopy equivalent, which means: what should one ask to make this true? Does anybody know where I can find a precise (and possibly correct) formulation? My mind relates this to the name of Karoubi, but Google did not help.

A more precise (and possible less hopeless) question. Let $I\subsetneq \mathfrak{m}$ be a principal ideal of $A$, generated by a non-zero divisor. Let $X=\mathrm{Spec}({A})$, $Y=\mathrm{Spec}({A/I})$. One has a canonical push forward map

$$i_{*}\colon K(Y)\to K(X)$$
giving the corresponding morphism on $K_0$ groups.

Consider an $A$-module $M$, finitely generated, of finite projective dimension (i.e. admitting a finite projective resolution). I want to understand when $[M]$ in $K_0(A)$ is in the image of the push forward map from $K_0(A/I)$, i.e. when there is a $K_0$ class $\alpha\in K_0(A/I)$ such that $i_{*}(\alpha) = [M]$.

**Question 2:** can I replace $A$ with $\hat{A}$ to answer to this kind of questions? Which extra condition should I add to $M$ in order to be able to descend the answer on $\hat{A}$ to an answer on $A$?

Comment: This seems to have been asked already: mathoverflow.net/q/159412/13653. I'm going to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @ToddTrimble My fault: I reposted the question with minor modifications and I flagged for migration in Math.Stackexchange. Sorry.